# Как переслать массив чисел на сервер?

Tags: c#

Я знаю, что можно переслать текст с помощью `byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mas);` Вот, если у меня mas - это массив чисел, то как его переслать и выловить на сервере? Ловлю на сервере таким образом:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
```

Comment: что есть сервер? работает WCF? API? Self-Host? давайте отходить от двух последних вариантов. Создаете контроллер под post запрос и отправляете туда все, что нужно без всей этой манипуляции. Подходит?